# Restoring backup files

Tags: shell, backup, rename

I have a directory in which are listed some `.py` files and some `.py.bak` files. I want to delete the `.py` files and restore the backup file renaming them `*.py`. Is there a shell script that can do this?

Thank you,
rubik

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a busybody, but it sounds like something you should be using version control for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do. Be sure to test on files you wouldn't mind losing.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f *.py
for fn in *.py.bak
do
  mv "${fn}" "${fn%%.bak}"
done
```

Comment: The problem with this command is that not all files necessarily have bak files so it would be nice to check up first only files which have bak files and then remove after verification.